# Looping so that it extracts data and then calculates mean

Tags: r

I have been trying to calculate mean for `"Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"` for `data(iris)` by factor `"Species"`.

I know that we can easily do this with `aggregate()` or `apply()` families, but I am trying to do this by writing a function that could possibly do the same thing.

What I have been trying to do was:
(1) Create a subset that is divided by "Species"
(2) Calculate mean for each column for the subset
(3) Combine into one table

```
new_iris <- function(df) {

  # Enter code here
  species = levels(df$Species)

  for (i in 1:length(species)) {
  subdata = subset(df, Species == species[i])
  means = colMeans(subdata[1:4])
}
 data.frame(species,means)
  }
```

The first problem I have was the subsetting part, which I hope to loop so that it returns three sets of subdata. But instead, it returns for only one type like "virginica" when I was hoping to see separate subsets of other types as well.

This problem again is connected to forming a data frame. Since the length is not equal, it doesn't allow me to create a new data frame of calculated means according to species.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you're doing is some form of educational exercise; so I won't comment on other/better methods here.

There are a few issues with your code, so here is an improved version

```
new_iris <- function(df) {

  # Enter code here
  species = levels(df$Species)

  data.frame(
      species,
      do.call(rbind, lapply(species, function(x)
          colMeans(df[df$Species == x, ][1:4]))))
}


new_iris(iris)
#species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
#2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
#3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Some comments:

1. It's better/faster to use direct indexing of rows than `subset`.
2. There's no need for a `for` loop inside your function; you can use `lapply` to generate a `list` of results for every element of `species`; then use `do.call(rbind, ...)` to row-bind results together.
3. Usually the point of writing a function is to make it easier to provide the same functionality to different data. In the case of your function this is difficult as you implicitly assume the following things about your data `df`

   - `df` must contain a column `Species`
   - `df$Species` must be a `factor`

   There are no safety checks in your function, so if you pass data that does not have the "correct" format the function will throw a fairly nondescript error.